# What am I - "Big" Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Big I am, but small I eat,
Above or below, I'm really neat,
My brothers have one, but I have two,
You will not find me at the zoo,
I'll travel with others, but not for long,
You'll travel to hear my song.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess it's

> a humpback whale

but I can't quite figure out how "My brothers have one, but I have two" applies.

Reasons:

Big I am, but small I eat,

> Whales are big, eat plankton (small)

Above or below, I'm really neat,

> Whales swim (below) and can jump out of the water (above), and are cool.

My brothers have one, but I have two,

You will not find me at the zoo,

> Too big to have whales at the zoo

I'll travel with others, but not for long,

> Migrate with others for breeding, but then travel alone

You'll travel to hear my song.

> Whales sing

Comment: Very nice and fast! Still looking for someone that can figure out the "My brothers have one, but I have two."

Comment: It's a female talking, but I cannot find the difference between male and females that relates to one and two...getting close?

Comment: Some whales have two blowholes, others have one.
If that is what the clue is referring to the correct answer should be a "baleen whale".
link:


http://animals.pawnation.com/whales-two-blow-holes-5671.html

Comment: @Ciacciu The above mentioned type of whale has two blowholes as well.

Comment: @AggieKidd Oops, you're right of course, i misremembered the riddle when I posted the comment :)

Comment: For whatever it's worth, "Baleen" isn't a species of whale, it's a category.  The categories are "baleen" vs "toothed" and there are 14 species of baleen whale, of which humpback is one.

Comment: Humpback whales evolved from even-toed ungulates. Camels are also even-toed ungulates, and have two humps.